Issue with Discord.js: "Interaction has already been acknowledged" and "Unknown interaction" Errors
I'm developing a Discord bot using Discord.js and encountering some issues with button interactions in a specific command. When I try to update an interaction for the second time, I get the following errors:
Error 1: Interaction has already been acknowledged
Error updating interaction: DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\Nobre\Desktop\NobreAssistente\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:730:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\Nobre\Desktop\NobreAssistente\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:835:23)
    at async _REST.request (C:\Users\Nobre\Desktop\NobreAssistente\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1278:22)
    at async ButtonInteraction.deferUpdate (C:\Users\Nobre\Desktop\NobreAssistente\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:203:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/Nobre/Desktop/NobreAssistente/commands/entrevistar.js:84:17) {
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: { type: 6 } },
  rawError: {
    message: 'Interaction has already been acknowledged.',
    code: 40060
  },
  code: 40060,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1246619836952612877/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTI0NjYxOTgzNjk1MjYxMjg3NzpSalZYaHZ3U2lmd2JkRXVjQ1BuTncweTdrMnNuSGdaaW5CQmNZb1BkZmlTOHBzR3VRSmpSdDlITXBxVXpBSWpqT29UdXpHRnNmMnBhU1lnZXZudGhPYjNMVnRWNmJIOWZTSWhpc3JoTlU2aWhPcVVkWWoxUDJ1MXhGMFlRYWExMg/callback'
}

Error 2: Unknown interaction
Error updating interaction: DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\Nobre\Desktop\NobreAssistente\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:730:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\Nobre\Desktop\NobreAssistente\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:835:23)
    at async _REST.request (C:\Users\Nobre\Desktop\NobreAssistente\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1278:22)
    at async ButtonInteraction.deferUpdate (C:\Users\Nobre\Desktop\NobreAssistente\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:203:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/Nobre/Desktop/NobreAssistente/commands/entrevistar.js:90:17) {
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: { type: 6 } },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1246619842845479073/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTI0NjYxOTg0Mjg0NTQ3OTA3MzpHOUlQdERGeHRFRWpHc2J0ZjBoc01HVGZaZXJGWU5ZV3lsWW9PQjZRVjVCMDBPQWswMkRJRDBSbTgybVBvYmE0WklTVFlJMEVpR2RuYXZlSTlHS2JoOUp1azBiNnZ0QkVxZ3ZiMnZHUkxENTRHZG9CODBVYnZLWXFQREgwQnY0NA/callback'
}

Additional Error 3:
C:\Users\Nobre\Desktop\NobreAssistente\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:730
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
            ^

DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\Nobre\Desktop\NobreAssistente\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:730:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\Nobre\Desktop\NobreAssistente\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:835:23)
    at async _REST.request (C:\Users\Nobre\Desktop\NobreAssistente\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1278:22)
    at async ButtonInteraction.deferUpdate (C:\Users\Nobre\Desktop\NobreAssistente\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:203:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/Nobre/Desktop/NobreAssistente/commands/entrevistar.js:149:25) {
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: { type: 6 } },
  rawError: {
    message: 'Interaction has already been acknowledged.',
    code: 40060
  },
  code: 40060,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1246619853914247259/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTI0NjYxOTg1MzkxNDI0NzI1OTpERmQzTUlGNkdqbnRxU1lLVjNQU1Iwb0FTNmh2UURscWNQdDJ5clU1YmpoNnFuTmM3czJXellKM092RVNvbDZ3dFg0WnR4dkViOG1ncVZyQkhJVXZRTWpNZjQ0OTNzY0FMVFFremoyTjZuRGsyUnFmUmxwVDdFTkxBR2hPTUxDMg/callback'
}

Context
The issue seems to occur when trying to reuse the /entrevistar command after the initial usage. The bot attempts to defer an update or send a follow-up to an interaction that has already been acknowledged or no longer exists.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken

Ensured Single Acknowledgement: Checked that each interaction is only acknowledged once.
Interaction Validity: Confirmed that the interaction is still valid before attempting to update or defer it.

Research
I have searched extensively for solutions to this issue but haven't found any relevant information. Most resources discuss basic interaction handling but don't address this specific problem of reusing interactions or handling multiple acknowledgements.
Full Code
Here's the full code for the /entrevistar command, including the button interaction handling:
import {
    SlashCommandBuilder,
    EmbedBuilder,
    ButtonBuilder,
    ButtonStyle,
    ActionRowBuilder,
    ModalBuilder,
    TextInputBuilder,
    TextInputStyle
} from 'discord.js';
import fs from 'fs';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname, join } from 'path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
const entrevistasFile = join(__dirname, 'entrevistas.json');
const LOG_CHANNEL_ID = '1246106949930582066';
const ERROR_CHANNEL_ID = '1246613947197685850'; // ID do canal de erros

let entrevistas = [];

export const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('entrevistar')
    .setDescription('Inicia uma entrevista.')
    .addStringOption(option =>
        option.setName('nick')
            .setDescription('Nickname do entrevistado')
            .setRequired(true));

export async function execute(interaction, client) {
    const nick = interaction.options.getString('nick');
    const interviewer = interaction.user.username;

    // Carrega as entrevistas anteriores, se houver
    if (fs.existsSync(entrevistasFile)) {
        entrevistas = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(entrevistasFile));
    }

    // Encontra o último ID registrado
    const lastID = entrevistas.length > 0 ? entrevistas[entrevistas.length - 1].id : 0;
    const newID = lastID + 1;

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor(0x0099FF)
        .setTitle(`Entrevista de ${nick}`)
        .setAuthor({ name: `Entrevistado por: ${interviewer}` })
        .setDescription(`Entrevista de número #${newID}\nDuração: 0s`)
        .setColor('White')
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Link da entrevista', value: 'Ainda não foi adicionado' }
        )
        .setFooter({ text: 'é isso' })
        .setThumbnail('https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/fYS2lajU9tpJJtML1tW-r5Gb1QrxSxw1ObWV-2rYY08/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/1246188022005760072/93ed652d6ca440e3beca11d58353fb47.webp?format=webp&width=115&height=115')
        .setTimestamp();

    const startButton = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('start_interview')
        .setLabel('Iniciar entrevista')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary);

    const endButton = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('end_interview')
        .setLabel('Finalizar entrevista')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
        .setDisabled(true);

    const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(startButton, endButton);

    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [row], ephemeral: false });

    let startTime;
    let endTime;

    const filter = i => i.customId === 'start_interview' || i.customId === 'end_interview';
    const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 3600000 });

    collector.on('collect', async i => {
        try {
            if (i.customId === 'start_interview') {
                startTime = Date.now();
                startButton.setDisabled(true);
                endButton.setDisabled(false);
                await i.deferUpdate(); // Deferir a interação ao invés de atualizá-la imediatamente
                await i.editReply({ components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(startButton, endButton)] });
            } else if (i.customId === 'end_interview') {
                endTime = Date.now();
                const duration = Math.floor((endTime - startTime) / 1000);
                embed.setDescription(`Entrevista de número #${newID}\nDuração: ${duration}s`);
                await i.deferUpdate(); // Deferir a interação ao invés de atualizá-la imediatamente
                await i.editReply({ embeds: [embed], components: [] });

                const logChannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(LOG_CHANNEL_ID);
                if (!logChannel) {
                    return interaction.followUp({ content: 'Canal de logs não encontrado. Verifique se o ID do canal está correto.', ephemeral: true });
                }
                const logEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setTitle(`Entrevista de ${nick}`)
                    .setDescription(`Entrevista #${newID}\nDuração: ${duration}s`)
                    .setAuthor({ name: `Entrevistado por: ${interviewer}` })
                    .setColor('White')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Link da entrevista', value: 'Ainda não foi adicionado' }
                    )
                    .setFooter({ text: 'é isso' })
                    .setTimestamp();

                entrevistas.push({ id: newID, nick, interviewer, duration });

                // Salva todas as entrevistas no arquivo
                fs.writeFileSync(entrevistasFile, JSON.stringify(entrevistas, null, 2));

                await logChannel.send({ embeds: [logEmbed] });

                const attachButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('attach_proof')
                    .setLabel('Anexar link')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary);

                const cancelButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('cancel_proof')
                    .setLabel('Não anexar')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);

                const proofRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(attachButton, cancelButton);

                await interaction.followUp({ content: 'Entrevista finalizada! Deseja anexar o link da entrevista?', components: [proofRow], ephemeral: true });

                const proofFilter = btn => btn.customId === 'attach_proof' || btn.customId === 'cancel_proof';
                const proofCollector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: proofFilter, time: 60000 });

                proofCollector.on('collect', async btn => {
                    if (btn.customId === 'attach_proof') {
                        const modal = new ModalBuilder()
                            .setCustomId('proof_modal')
                            .setTitle('Link da Entrevista');

                        const linkInput = new TextInputBuilder()
                            .setCustomId('proof_link')
                            .setLabel('Link da Entrevista')
                            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
                            .setRequired(true);

                        const modalRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(linkInput);
                        modal.addComponents(modalRow);

                        await btn.showModal(modal);
                    } else if (btn.customId === 'cancel_proof') {
                        await btn.deferUpdate();
                        await btn.editReply({ content: 'Entrevista registrada sem link.', components: [] });
                    }
                });

                interaction.client.on('interactionCreate', async modalInteraction => {
                    if (!modalInteraction.isModalSubmit()) return;

                    if (modalInteraction.customId === 'proof_modal') {
                        const proofLink = modalInteraction.fields.getTextInputValue('proof_link');
                        logEmbed.setFields({ name: 'Link da entrevista', value: proofLink });
                        await logChannel.send({ embeds: [logEmbed] });
                        await modalInteraction.reply({ content: 'Link da entrevista registrado com sucesso!', ephemeral: true });
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Erro ao atualizar interação:', error);
            sendErrorToChannel(interaction, error, 'atualizar a interação');
        }
    });

    collector.on('end', collected => {
        // Finaliza o coletor quando o tempo expirar
    });
}

async function sendErrorToChannel(interaction, error, action) {
    const errorChannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(ERROR_CHANNEL_ID);
    if (errorChannel) {
        await errorChannel.send(`Registrado erro em tentar ${action}! Informações gerais do erro:\n\`\`\`Erro: ${error.message}\`\`\`\n\`\`\`${error.stack}\`\`\``);
    } else {
        console.error('Canal de erros não encontrado. Verifique se o ID do canal está correto.');
    }
}


Any insights or suggestions on how to handle these errors properly would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
I have searched extensively for solutions to this issue but haven't found any relevant information. Most resources discuss basic interaction handling but don't address this specific problem of reusing interactions or handling multiple acknowledgements.

Have you tried to use await i.deferReply({ ephemeral: true }); instead of i.deferUpdate()?
